# Picasso default downloader

Tags: android, download, picasso, okhttp

Just a simple question: what is the Picasso (2.5.*) default downloader?
I know I can use OkHttp

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
    .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
    .build();
```

but if I don't, whats the default Picasso downloader? And what's advantages to use OkHttp with Picasso?

Comment: correct answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143949/picasso-and-okhttp/32144138#32144138

Answer (score 0):

The default class that implements Downloader interface is [UrlConnectionDownloader](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/UrlConnectionDownloader.java) if OkHttpClient class isn't in your class path.

The [overview](http://square.github.io/okhttp/#overview) of OkHttp library should respond to your second question.