# Picasso and OkHttp

Tags: java, android, picasso, okhttp

A question about a thing that I don't understand:

does `Picasso` use `OkHttp` as default downloader, or should I configure it by myself?

And - if not - why should I use `Picasso` *with* `OkHttp`? What are the advantages compared to the default `Picasso`?

Thanks.

(currently I'm using `Picasso v.2.5.2`)

Comment: I briefly checked the source code and they are using OkHttp which they developed.

Comment: @Blackbelt so I don't need to explicitly use OkHttp, right? It's the default behaviour for Picasso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OkHttp is available in your project, Picasso will use it. If not, Picasso will fall back to `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: It's enough to compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    and 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0' in Gradle?

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio: Again, you don't have to do *anything*. Picasso will fall back to `HttpUrlConnection` if OkHttp is not there. If you *do* want to use OkHttp, then `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0` should suffice.